# Strange issue for creating a UIView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, nib

1>1st project :
I have created a window based cocoa touch app just for test, it's straight forward and easy.
It's basically just loading the view from the Nib file but have some code in the

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipod.jpg"];
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame];
    imageView.image = image;
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

}
```

It works fine and just give me a simple image view.

2>2nd proejct

But when I trying to integrate those code into another cocoa project as the 1st view of a navigation

controller, it only gives me a white blank screen.

I basically specified the Nib file in the interface builder(under Navigation controller / view controller) "NIB Name", and it only loads me a white blank view as if the code for adding the image view is not working. Why ??? 
BTW The viewdidload code above did run as I put a break point there, but it's not giving me the image view.

One thing I did notice is when I create the UIImageView using Interface build instead of doing it by code in viewdidload, it works fine in the 2nd porject .

So I am wondering why the code not working fine for the 2nd project and How to make it work using code?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your view is wired up to the ViewControllers view outlet? The only other thing I can think of is that maybe you don't have iPod.jpg included in the second project?

Comment: Yes, the outlet it's actually generated by cmd+drag from IB, so it definitely wired. Also the iPod.jpg is included in the 2nd project. I couldn't figure out why but I am currently using the workaround by specific everything in IB include the imageView.